# Compile static library using g++

Tags: linux

I have 3 classes - I denote those by `firstClass`,`secondClass`,`thirdClass`.
My headers - `firstClass.h`, `secondClass.h`, `thirdClass.h` and sources `firstClass.cpp`, `secondClass.cpp`, `thirdClass.cpp`.
In class `thirdClass` I create instance of `firstClass` and two instance of `secondClass`.
In `main.cpp` I deamonize and create instance `thirdClass`.

I want to create static library of `thirdclass` and linking to `main.cpp`.
`firstClass` and `thirdClass` used the same library `libm.a`

I created library step by step as following:

1. `g++ -c -I-/usr/include/ -I-/usr/lib/ -I-/home/projects/Learninig firstClass.cpp -lstdc++ -lm-o WsChannel.o -w -m32`
2. `g++ -c -I-/usr/include/ -I-/usr/lib/ --I-/home/projects/Learninig secondClass  -lstdc++ -o secondClass.o -w -m32`
3. `g++ -c -I-/usr/include/ -I-/usr/lib/ --I-/home/projects/Learninig  thirdClass.cpp -lstdc++ -lm -o thirdClass.o -w -m32`
4. `ar rcs libLearning.a firstClass.o secondClass.o thirdClass.o`
5. `g++ main.cpp -L. -lLearning -lm -o MnLearning.o -m32`

Compiling was maked correctly without any errors, but when I execute program I have same error. I spent some hours on checking code, but I don't find bugs. So then maybe compiling was incorrect. I did this using some tutorial in web.
If whatever was unclearly I am ready to more explain my question.

**Edit:** My error:
`segfault at 557400000045 ip 00005574bd509dcd sp 00007ffd9e887900 error 4 in MnLearning[5574bd4f2000+26000]`

Comment: If you have an error please add it to the question otherwise it will be very hard to know what you're actually asking.

Comment: Why do you use `-m32` if you have a 64 bits processor and OS ?

Comment: Machine where I execute programm have 32 bits processor and OS.

Comment: Then you'll better debug first your program on your own (64 bits) Linux system, and only once it has no apparent bugs for your system start porting it to 32 bits.

Comment: *"maybe compiling was incorrect"* - as a general rule of thumb it is much more likely that your code has an error than that the compiler makes a mistake

Comment: BTW `secondClass` is a very poor name (unless your problem is about tickets for railroad trains with both first class and second class passengers). It is important to write *readable* code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is surely inside your own source code. Avoid [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) in it, and be [scared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108) of UB.

Your use of [`-I-`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html) is strange, and probably wrong. I recommend removing it (and also, at first, remove the `-m32` flag if your computer and distribution is 64 bits; work first to have your program run correctly on your laptop, then port it later to 32 bits Linux by adding the `-m32` flag). You might use [preprocessor options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) like `-H` to be shown what files are included.

I recommend building your library and your program with some [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation) tool, such as [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](http://ninja-build.org/).

Configure your build to compile with all warnings and debug info, i.e. using `g++ -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/). Improve your source code to get no warnings. Then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program (and library).

> So then maybe compiling was incorrect.

No, the compiler is probably good, and you should trust it.

**The bug is very likely to be in your own code.**

> My error: segfault at 557400000045 ip 00005574bd509dcd sp 00007ffd9e887900 error 4 in MnLearning[5574bd4f2000+26000]

[Segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) is a symptom of some error in your own code (e.g. some buffer overflow, some bad pointer dereference, etc; or other kind of UB).

You might also use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

> I spent some hours on checking code, but I don't find bugs.

You did not spend enough time (some bugs may take you weeks of work to be found), and you forgot to use the debugger, a very handy tool to help you understand the behavior of your program and find bugs in it. Be aware that [programming is difficult](http://norvig.com/21-days.html), and don't be discouraged.

Comment: Before compiling on g ++ I try used Visual Studio 2017, but I abandoned. Maybe I should try in CodeBlocks on Windows? On linux I am new.

Comment: No, keep working on Linux. It is very developer- and student- friendly. You just need to learn more about how to use it wisely. And CodeBlocks is not a compiler, but an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) which runs compilation commands (and hides them from you). You are right in compiling on Linux thru commands.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yesterday I saw for a moment my code, but today I found a mistake. Again thanks for suggestions and a bucket of cold water.